# javaScript placeholder in array for pattern match

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, pattern-matching, placeholder

I have a js array like that:

```
let data = [{status:"stay",points:[1,2,3,4,5]}, {status:"move",points:[1,2,3,4,5]},{status:"stay",points:[1,2,3,4,5]}]
```

And I want to do some pattern match, here is my code:

```
switch (data){
    case [{status:"move",_},{status:"stay",_},{status:"move",_}]:
        console.log("successfully!")
}
```

And I don't care the points array, but in js the placeholder "_" not exist, actually I know other method to do this, but if we just use switch-case, can it be solved?

I am a newbie of js, anynoe knows how to do it?

Comment: whta is the content of underscore `_`?

Comment: array,  {status:"stay",points:[1,2,3,4,5]}

Comment: you have an array, you need to iterate it for getting a wanted `status`. but what would you do then if any found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you might try reducing your array to a string, and then use that string in the switch statement. Something like this:

```
var actionString = ""

data.forEach(function(datum) {
    actionString += datum.status + ' ';
});

// Remove extra space at the end
actionString.trim();

console.log(actionString); // "move stay move"
```

Then your switch statement would be:

```
switch(actionString) {
    case "move stay move":
        console.log('success!');
        break;
    case "stay move stay":
        console.log('failure?');
        break;
    /* etc */
}
```

Comment: Perfectly!  it seems that we can not use some placeholder syntax in js?

Comment: You can also create `actionString` like that : `actionString = data.map((d) => d.status).join(' ')`

Comment: @Yang Unfortunately not. Maybe you could try looking into a functional library like lodash. There might be something there, but ultimately it will be a workaround, as pattern matching is not a native feature of js.

Comment: @NathanP. That's true, that would certainly be more succinct. For some reason I wasn't sure if map was widely supported in browsers as I've only used it in node

Comment: @MichaelHorn Thanks a billion, I came up with this question when I converted Scala code into js code.

Comment: @Yang Glad I could help :)

Comment: @Yang Hey again, just wanted to call your attention to something interesting I found. There's a language called Purescript that compiles into javascript. It's purely functional, strongly typed and it supports pattern matching. Very similar to Haskell, if you've ever worked with that. I just thought of this question when I found out about it

Comment: @MichaelHorn That sounds interesting, I'II try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
switch (data.status){
    case "stay":
    case "move":
        console.log("successfully!")
        break;
}
```

Documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: Thanks,  data is a array with many object like  {status:"stay",points:[1,2,3,4,5]}, I need to match the first three object's status, it may be stay&move&stay or move&stay&move or others.